# How to handle bitmap for tablet?

Tags: android, bitmap

I put my bitmaps to drawable-hdpi and they look good in my Nexus One(hdpi).
But when I run app in Nexus 7(mdpi), they look small.

Do I have to enlarge bitmaps and put in drawable-large for Nexus 7?
And do I have to put bitmaps in drawable-xlarge for 10 inch tablet?
Is there better solution than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your drawables into drawable-xlarge only and these will be resized on the fly for lesser resolutions. However, it is better to create bitmap sets for each dpi/size since then you can tailor screens to the needed precision. Also you probably better of adding layout flavors as well so each layout will use appropriate bitmaps

Answer (score 0):

The OS will scale the images for you. The nexus 7 is tvdpi Iirc

Comment: OS scaled bitmaps smaller because Nexus One is hdpi and Nexus 7 is mdpi or tvdpi. That is the problem.

Comment: How can OS scale them up? Because Nexus 7's density is lower than Nexus One, it scale them down. I only use dip or sp in layout.

Comment: Sorry, yeah tvdpi is below hdpi.  If you don't want the system to scale your images you can use -nodpi but they'll look small higher resolution screens. If you put them into a -tvdpi folder it'll use those and not scale them down either

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article first [Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html#create-bitmaps)

Also use only dp(dip) units in your layouts(don't use px).

Comment: I know that and I read that. I could not find answer. My app must work for API 7 and greater.